# Add multiple values to cookie jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
<img src="http://website1.com/img.jpg" class="image" />
<img src="http://website1.com/img2.jpg" class="image" />
<img src="http://website1.com/img3.jpg" class="image" />
<img src="http://website1.com/img4.jpg" class="image" />
```

That is how my source code looks. I need to add the src value to the same cookie. My friend told me you could seperate it with a comma, but I'm not sure how I can do that with my code.

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    $.cookie("images", $(this).attr('src'), {expires: 9999999999});
}
```

That one works, but it will override the current cookie, which means I can only have 1 image in the cookie at the same time.

EDIT: I might as well tell you what I need it for. I need to extract the values from the images, and put them in img-tags.

```
.append('<img src=' + $.cookie("images") + ' />')
```

That's how I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    $.cookie("images",$.cookie("images") + ","+ $(this).attr('src'), {expires: 9999999999});
}
```

When you want to append, do it like this:

```
var imgSrc = $.cookie("images").split(",");

for (var i=0;i<imgSrc.length;i++){
   if (imgSrc[i]!=""){
      .append("<img src='" + imgSrc[i] + "' />");
   }
}
```

Or

```
$.each($.cookie("images").split(","), function(index, value) {
   if (value !=""){
      .append("<img src='" + value + "' />");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the job.
How would I do the split on load now?